# src files in sub folders in QNX momentics IDE not compile

Tags: compiler-errors, eclipse-cdt, subdirectory, qnx

I'm going to re-ask a question belonging to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418452/source-files-in-project-subfolder-not-compile-qnx-momentics-ide because I'm having the exact same issue and after google it for several hours/days/.. I'm not finding any help and the thread I mention before wasn't answer by anybody, I hope not to get the same luck.

I'm going to explain the issue: I'm developing right now for Blackberrys new O.S. BB10, which recommends the QNX Momentics IDE for developing in C/C  /Qt/QML etc. The IDE, as is said in a comment in the thread above, is a re-package/bundle of Eclipse with the Eclipse CDT plugin and some custom QNX tool extensions. The thing is that when I'm trying to organize my code files into subfolder in the main src folder, those files will not compile, wich keep the program from running successfuly obviously. Please if you know why this is happening give me a hand :) .

I've found some sites about Eclipse where they said that I need to add the subfolders to the "path and symbols" settings of the project. And I did that, and nothing seems to change. I also tried to create a new src foulder instead of a regular folder, but when I'm trying to do it I get the following error:  Invalid project path: Duplicate path entries found.

So fellows this is driving me crazy, I have like 50 C   classes in the root src folder right now. Help please!.

Greetings!..

Answer (score 0):

If using the "GNU"-type builds, the QNX build structure generally has the "Makefile" in each subdir that's has a few QRECURSE lines to make for a recursive build.

See: http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.2/neutrino/prog/make_convent.html

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed answer, but we stumbled onto this issue this week, and I figured I'd share our solution.

In our project root, an auto-generated Makefile contains the following rule:
$(MAKE) -Csrc hinstall

The hinstall copies only the headers from the project into the build, but as we never changed any headers (only source), this makes no difference.

Modifying the Makefile to:
$(MAKE) -Csrc install

Forced the build process to consider all changes.